# Display an overlay over UI

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to create an overlay that stays visible on top of all views?

For example, a webview with a Facebook 'like' button in the corner.

Comment: Yes. Add a view on top of all view. If you add a view, bring the view which should be on top in foreground again with [bringSubviewToFront:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront:)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it to the App delegates window:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#define kDelegate ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

...

[kDelegate.window addSubview:overlay];
```

But it all depends on how your view hierarchy is set up.

Comment: This is a swift question =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a `UIWindow` with property `windowLevel` set to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar`

There are good examples on Github named as something like "status bar alert" to learn from.